# Is there anyway I can display all the contents of a Stack widget which has a List of dynamically created Positioned widgets as its children?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Here is my code for build method,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Game Screen'),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        //widget 1..
      ),
      Expanded(
        //widget 2..
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Stack(         // Problem is with this stack widget
          children: cardList, // dynamically generated list of Positioned Widgets.
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);}
```

I tried enclosing this `Stack` Widget inside `FittedBox` widget. Hoping, that it would scale the contents of the `Stack` but sadly it gives an error saying that "The child of FittedBox should be Finite Sized". But my stack is displaying a dynamically generated list of `Positioned` Widgets so it could not be finite sized. Any workaround this?

P.S. I dont want to use List View, I want to scale the contents of the stack.. Just like how we witness it when using FittedBox Widget.